# Makefile with directory for object files

Tags: makefile

I have the following structure for a project and I am just starting to introduce a Makefile to build the software:

```
├── Makefile
├── README.md
├── cg
│   └── cg.c
└── utilities
   ├── utilities.c
   └── utilities.h
```

I am trying to put object files in a directory called obj yet I can't seem to get it working.

My makefile looks like:

```
CC=mpicc
CFLAGS=-O3 -std=c99
LIBS=
MKDIR_P = mkdir -p

make_build_dir:
    @mkdir -p obj/

utilities.o: utilities/utilities.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o ./obj/$@ -c $<

cg.o: cg/cg.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o ./obj/$@ -c $<

.PHONY: make_build_dir

cg.exe: make_build_dir utilities.o cg.o 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -fr obj
    rm cg.exe
```

Yet this generates the following error:

```
a@a:b/b ‹master*›$ make cg.exe
mpicc -O3 -std=c99 -o ./obj/utilities.o -c utilities/utilities.c
mpicc -O3 -std=c99 -o ./obj/cg.o -c cg/cg.c
cg/cg.c:133:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'decompose' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  decompose(num_chunks, chunks_per_rank,me, &settings); 
  ^
1 warning generated.
mpicc -O3 -std=c99 -o cg.exe make_build_dir
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'make_build_dir'
make: *** [cg.exe] Error 1
```

How can I get it to generate the object files in the obj directory and then an executable in the top-level directory?

Comment: The target `make_build_dir` is accompanied by the rule `mkdir -p obj`, you might want to quickly fix that?

Comment: @lubgr How do you mean? Don't I need a rule to create the obj directory?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the snippet, forget about that. From the error message it seems that `make_build_dir` is passed to `$(CC)` somewhere, though. Does this happen during object creation or linking?

Comment: I'll append the full output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This linking part of the makefile

```
cg.exe: make_build_dir utilities.o cg.o 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

has two issues. First, `$<` refers to the first prerequesite of the target `cg.exe`, and that is `make_build_dir`. Declaring it as `.PHONY` doesn't help here, it's simply passed to `$(CC)`. Second, `utilities.o cg.o` both don't exist at this location. You can change the rule to

```
cg.exe: obj/utilities.o obj/cg.o 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

Note the automatic variable `$^` which refers to all prerequisites. Additionally, the object file targets should be

```
obj/cg.o: cg/cg.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

(identical for `utilities.o`).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to `make_build_dir` before making any `*.o` or `make` won't have a place to put them.

And you can make the `Makefile` more generic.

```
.PHONY: all clean info
.DEFAULT_GOAL := all

SRC_DIRS = cg utilities
OBJ_DIR  = obj
EXE      = cg.exe

SOURCES = $(foreach path, $(SRC_DIRS), $(wildcard $(path)/*.c))
OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/, $(notdir $(SOURCES:%.c=%.o)))

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: */%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

all: make_build_dir $(EXE)

info:
    $(info SOURCES=$(SOURCES))
    $(info OBJECTS=$(OBJECTS))

make_build_dir:
    @mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)

$(EXE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

With this `Makefile`, you can add more source directories to `SRC_DIRS` and it will automatically compile sources in them.

What does it do? Run `make` with the `-n` option to see:

```
$ make -n
mkdir -p obj
cc  -o obj/cg.o -c cg/cg.c
cc  -o obj/utilities.o -c utilities/utilities.c
cc  -o cg.exe obj/cg.o obj/utilities.o
```

You can also display the info on the variables by:

```
$ make info
SOURCES= cg/cg.c  utilities/utilities.c
OBJECTS=obj/cg.o obj/utilities.o
```